# Owebia Shipping Show Always 0 Magento 1.9.4

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I install Owebia Shipping Magento 1.9.4 But Its not Working, Is show always 0. Use simple rules:

```
{
 "id_04" : {
 "label" : "Days Shipping" ,
 "shipto" : "US" ,
 "fees" : "{quote.grand_total}*0.20"
}
```

But It always shows bellow image please check it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba6fQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try {cart.price+tax+discount} instead of {quote.grand_total}